# Different RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f interpretation

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have configured a common rewrite rule to forward all request to non-existing paths to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?__s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I have a different behaviour on
**debian 8 (jessie)** compared with **fedora 24 (Twenty Four)**

Following setup:

- /.htaccess (with above rules)
- /index.php
- /example/test.php

if I call the following URL: http://myserver.local/example/test

The behaviour is not the same on debian and fedora.

On debian, the apache says "ok, file test or folder test not found in example folder" forward to index.php (expected behaviour).

On fedora, the apache says "oh, i have found a file called test.php and do not forward to index.php. So I deliver test.php to my client."
If I remove or rename the test.php it is forwarding to index.php as expected.

Is anybody able to explain why the same .htaccess is interpeted in a different way on debian and fedora?

Comment: if you hides an extention, then specify a visible routine doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is anybody able to explain why the same .htaccess is interpeted in a different way on debian and fedora?

This is most likely due to `MultiViews` option in enabled state on your Fedora host.

Just place this line on top of your .htaccess to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

[`MultiViews` option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/test` is the URL then Apache will serve matching `/test.php`.

Comment: Very useful answer. Thanks anyway. I will try it.